# Зацикленная зависимость пакетов

Tags: ubuntu, repository

Обнаружил, что в репозитории пакет `liblxc1` зависит от `lxc-common`, который в свою очередь зависит от `liblxc1`, из-за подобной зацикленной зависимости у меня не совсем корректно работает некий скрипт, хотелось узнать, является ли подобная зацикленная зависимость пакетов в репозитории обыденностью или может подобного быть не должно и это ошибка?

Comment: Нечасто, но и исключительным случаем это не назовёшь. А какая вообще разница скрипту кто от кого зависит?  Какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: впервые установил ubuntu server, не понравилось, что там по дефолту куча не нужных мне пакетов, составил набор правил для aptitude search чтоб можно было получить список пакетов, которые можно удалить, но автоматически aptitude search не позволяет обнаружить такие вот ситуации и поэтому в итоге данные пакеты не в списке пакетов, которые можно безопасно удалять